# Vulnerability in an inner package

Tags: c#

The nuget package `SouchProd.LinqToQuerystring.Core` in its latest version has a dependency on a package called `System.Net.Security` version 4.3.0.

This inner package has a vulnerability:

> Component System.Net.Security version 4.3.0 with ID nuget:System.Net.Security/4.3.0 violates policy High-Level Vulnerability: found vulnerability CVE-2017-0249 with severity HIGH and CVSS score 7.5
> (This vulnerability is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securityadvisories/2017/4021279 )

Like I said, this nuget package is already at its latest version... I need this package to converts a query string to a linq expression in an OData Web API (LinqToQueryString).

How can I fix something like that if its in an inner package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only bound to the vulnerable version if you let your dependency decide which version to take. If *you* add the nuget package yourself (so a fixed version of System.Net.Security, lets assume that's 4.3.x) to your project will work with the new(er) package.

Comment: but if its an inner package, how will the mother package implementation knows to use the newer version of the inner package instead of what is already inside the mother package?

Comment: They don't. The package still wants ">=4.3.0", but since you added "4.3.x", the assembly as a whole will be loaded using "4.3.x", because that satisfies both constraints. When adding the package directly, VS will create a binding redirect for you, so that all packages you use will use "4.3.x"

Comment: You can test that by compiling and making sure the dll in your output folder is really "4.3.x".

Comment: neat.. just wanted to know if there's a setting or somewhere that i can see that it does want ">4.3.0" and not "=4.3.0"?

Comment: That's in the dependencies of the package (can be seen e.g. in the bottom right hand corner of the Nuget package manager window of Visual Studio). I think it is always >=.

Comment: OK i saw it. Just FYI, I also see that it can be = and not always >=